# Something like setVisible() for Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aot, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there any way to do that?

I mean, if the form fullfill specific conditions setVisible true or false to a control in the form? Or if i check a CheckBox, show some specific ComboBox?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: sure, you can do it by code why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend enabling and disabling fields, rather than hiding them.

Open a Supplier, and on the *Invoice and Delivery* fast tab choose select the *Calculate withholding tax* CheckBox.  This is the *VendTable* form.
The *Calculate withholding tax* control will enable and disable a second control depending upon the value selected.

[image: VendTable.TaxWitholdCalculate]

The second control has it's property **AutoDeclaration** set to **Yes**, and the event that fires the change can be found on the forms *VendTable* data source.  Find the relevant field (VendTable > Data Sources > Vend Table > Fields > TaxWithholdCalculate) and notice that the *modified* method has been overridden, changing the control's **enabled** property.  It also has a **visible** property should you want to remove it from view.

[image: VendTable.TaxWitholdCalculate2]

Top Tip:  In case that you are not aware, you can right click on any control on a form and choose the *Personalise* option from the context menu.  From there is a form which contains a very useful box called System name.  You can find the name of the control/table field from this.

[image: VendTable.TaxWitholdCalculate3]

Comment: "I would recommend enabling and disabling fields, rather than hiding them."

Totally agree with that. The main reason for this is that when you dynamically hide / show controls, your form will shift controls due to Morphx handling layout of fields in groups.

Comment: @KennySaelen so you're saying that MorphX can't handle it well?

Comment: "I would recommend enabling and disabling fields, rather than hiding them." I would say in 99% of situations I have seen there has been a very good reason for hiding a UI field.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this solution for your second problem:

> if i check a CheckBox, show some specific ComboBox?

I assume your form is complete (it has all controls needed : comboboxes, checkboxes, etc). And the controls AutoDeclaration-property is set to 'Yes'.

1. In the AOT expand the Form till you find the CheckBox, expand it as well
2. Right-click its Methods and select 'Override method' >> 'Clicked'
3. Finally you can add this code and save/compile the form: 
   `myComboBox.visible(true);`

It should look like:

```
public void clicked()
{
    super();
    myComboBox.visible(true);
}
```